# How to solve bacula warning '"dbi:mysql" mismatched with the Database argument "MySQL" after upgrade?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, mysql

I recently upgraded a server from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.  After that, I keep getting a warning from bacula-daemon:

```
31-aoû 05:02 bacula-dir JobId 0: Warning: Dbdriver field within director config file "dbi:mysql" mismatched with the Database argument "MySQL" passed during Bacula compilation.
```

If `mysql` is not appropriate for `MySQL`, then what is appropriate? What should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it out: `dbi` does not exist anymore.  It is decided at build time.  During upgrade,a version compatible with MySQL has been installed, so this parm `dbi:mysql`is not neede anymore and deleted from config file.